# Can we restrict publish subitems count in sitecore if items more than 20

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore9

Want to restrict to publish items ,if  items count is more than 20.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an item validator, so that "the 21st" item and onward would fail validation so that it cannot transition to the final workflow step.

Another, more intrusive, alternative could potentially be having a `item:saved` processor that could set `__Never publish` to `1` to the surplus items, so they can't be published.

As a general recommendation, I'd say you should avoid changing the publishing pipeline. Try having all the items in a "good/valid" state instead, like the solutions above, where you don't change the behavior of Sitecore - rather just keep the content in a state that's in line with the application requirements.